# Custom TextView with Bluetooth Name

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

Im workin on a Custom TextView but im very frustraded with that. Idk how to complete the code.... My Code is:

```
public class TestTextView extends TextView{
static BluetoothSocket mSocket;
Context c;

public TestTextView(Context mContext){
    super(mContext);
    mBTConnected(c);
}

public static boolean mBTConnected(Context c){
    String mOutputName;
    Method m;
    try{
        BluetoothDevice mDevice=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice("MAC_ADRS");
        m=mDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
        mSocket=(BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(mDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));
        mSocket.connect();
        mOutputName=mDevice.getName().toString();

        Log.i("Bluetooth device "+mOutputName," is connected");

        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){

    }return false;
}}
```

Question: How do i set the String "name" as Text to the custom TextView to call it in my Xml layout file?

---

LOG:

```
10-10 17:34:14.900 E/SDAgentPackageStateReceiver(3797): Not going to handle 'com.mort015.BluetoothTextView'! 10-10 17:34:15.055 E/SDAgentPackageStateReceiver(3797): Not going to handle 'com.mort015.BluetoothTextView'! 10-10 17:34:18.610 E/SPPClientService(9467): [PackageInfoChangeReceiver] [handlePkgRemovedEvent] PackageName : com.mort015.BluetoothTextView, true, false 10-10 17:34:24.237 E/AndroidRuntime(30755): Process: com.mort015.BluetoothTextView, PID: 30755 10-10 17:34:24.237 E/AndroidRuntime(30755): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mort015.BluetoothTextView/com.mort015.BluetoothTextView.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.mort015.BluetoothTextView.TestTextView 10-10 17:34:24.237 E/AndroidRuntime(30755): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.mort015.BluetoothTextView.TestTextView 10-10 17:34:24.237 E/AndroidRuntime(30755): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.mort015.BluetoothTextView.TestTextView 10-10 17:34:24.237 E/AndroidRuntime(30755):     at com.mort015.BluetoothTextView.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 10-10 17:34:24.562 E/cm_cmc_c(5288): app launch:com.mort015.BluetoothTextView
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `mBtConnected` method non-static to get access to `this` object reference, then `setText(mOutputName)` inside `mBtConnected` method will do the job

Comment: Where exactly? when i tried all lines but it says error. "There is no such reference available here"

Comment: @user10479845 try `super.setText()`

Comment: I know what you mean. But where? wich line ? Btw i getting crash when open the app. Error while inflating layout with my custom textview edit: super.setText does not work too

Comment: @user10479845 do it just before the logging, when you got the name value.

Comment: Does not work... Says "There is no such reference available here"

Comment: @user10479845 does your IDE resolve reference to `super.setText()` inside `mBtConnected` method?

Comment: @user10479845 oh, forgot! Make `mBtConnected()` method non-static! If it's static, it must not use `this` and `super` references. And now use can get rid of `super.` mentioning

Comment: @user10479845 can you give more details about the error?

Comment: I can give a log. i also put my whole code here (Mainactivity, layout and textview class).

Comment: @user10479845 log will be enough I guess

Comment: @user10479845 so what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

i think i solved it:

```
public boolean mBTConnected(Context c){
    String mOutputName;
    Method m;

    try{
        BluetoothDevice mDevice=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice("MAC_ADRS");
        m=mDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
        mSocket=(BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(mDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));
        mSocket.connect();
        mOutputName=mDevice.getName();
        super.setText(mOutputName);
        Log.i("Bluetooth device "+mOutputName," is connected");


        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }return false;
}
```

My Layout file looks:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.myapp.myapp.TestTextView
    android:id="@+id/BtTxt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/></LinearLayout>
```

And my Mainactivity Java looks:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}}
```